# Product Listing with One Large Product View with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a product page with featured image, therefor I use unorder list tag and flexbox CSS. but I could not archive my goal,  I share this code on codepen as well and also attached required target, please help.

I tried code which I share on codepen:

'https://codepen.io/Muhammad-Fahim/pen/OJLjOoq'

I required below result

'https://i.ibb.co/WsQC8Ng/Group-189.jpg'

```css
$direction : left;

.product-listing-box {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: #{$direction};
    width: 100%;
    ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 30px 0px 0px;
        width: 100%;
        li {
            margin: 0px 0px 15px;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style-type: none;
            // float: #{$direction};
        }
        .pro-img {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            float: #{$direction};
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            img {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
        .pro-name {
            margin: 5px 0px 0px;
            padding: 0px 15px;
            float: #{$direction};
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .pro-description {
            margin: 5px 0px 0px;
            padding: 0px 15px;
            float: #{$direction};
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .pro-price {
            margin: 5px 0px 0px;
            padding: 0px 15px;
            float: #{$direction};
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }

    &.no-feature-product {
        ul {
            display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
            display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
            display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
            display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
            display: flex;

            // -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            // -moz-flex-direction: column;
            // -ms-flex-direction: column;
            // flex-direction: column;
            //
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;

            align-items: stretch;
            li {
                -webkit-flex: 1 0 25%;
                -moz-flex: 1 0 25%;
                -ms-flex: 1 0 25%;
                flex: 1 0 25%;
                &:first-child{
                    .pro-img {}
                    .pro-name {}
                    .pro-description {}
                    .pro-price {}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.feature-product {
        ul {
            display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
            display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
            display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
            display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
            display: flex;

            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-items: flex-start;
            li {
                display: flex; /* so child elements can use flexbox stuff too! */
                flex: 0 0 25%;
                align-items: flex-start;
                &:first-child{
                    flex: 0 0 50%;
                    .pro-img {}
                    .pro-name {}
                    .pro-description {}
                    .pro-price {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Product listing box Start Below -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-md-12 no-padding-md-lg">
        <div class="product-listing-box feature-product">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Product listing box End Above -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the html, define rows in div and properly use the `display: flex;` in these rows, you see in the design. You can refer the below HTML for reference.

```
<!-- Product listing box Start Below -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-md-12 no-padding-md-lg">
        <div class="product-listing-box feature-product">
            <ul>
                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                  <div style="flex: 2;"><li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                  </li></div>
                  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;flex: 1;">
                       <div style="flex: 1;display: flex;">
                  <li style="flex:1;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li style="flex:1;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                </div>
                  <div style="flex: 1;display: flex;">

                <li style="flex:1">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li style="flex: 1;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">
                        <span class="pro-img">
                            <img src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/133710-v6-realme-c2-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </span>
                        <span class="pro-name">Product name</span>
                        <span class="pro-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
                        <span class="pro-price">25.90</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Product listing box End Above -->
```

Comment: anything else you suggest in css without current structure changes.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with current HTML structure as all li elements are defined at one level. Maybe you can use CSS grid but that will also require you to write the HTML structure accordingly.